# Пакет Reflect. Заполнить массив структур

Tags: golang

имеется подобный код

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Name     string
    Password string
    Sex      string
}

func AddInfo(user interface{}, nameFields []string, userInfo []string) {
val := reflect.ValueOf(user).Elem()
for i := 0; i < len(nameFields); i++ {
    val.FieldByName(nameFields[i]).SetString(userInfo[i])
 }
}

func main() {
   user := &User{}
   nameFields := []string{"Name", "Password", "Sex"}
   userInfo := []string{"Kostya", "pas", "m"}
   AddInfo(user, nameFields, userInfo)
   fmt.Println("Name ", user.Name)
   fmt.Println("Password ", user.Password)
   fmt.Println("Sex ", user.Sex)
}
```

Код на Playground https://play.golang.org/p/1VnaVhqr0U

надо сделать тоже самое только заполнить структуру и положить ее в слайс.
надо создать слайс user := []User{}
сам процесс как это сделать знаю. проблема в том что не знаю как взять саму структуру
есть идея только передавать с слайсом еще и структуру. можно ли сделать так что бы передавать только слайс.
как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Так я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. размещаю ответ для таких же как я новичков в программировании, может кому понадобится.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Name     string
    Password string
    Sex      string
}

func AddInfo(user interface{}, userInfo []string) reflect.Value {
    valSlice := reflect.ValueOf(user).Elem()
    typeSlice := reflect.TypeOf(user).Elem().Elem()
    valStruct := reflect.New(typeSlice)
    valInterface := valStruct.Interface()
    val := reflect.ValueOf(valInterface).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        val.Field(i).SetString(userInfo[i])
    }
    slice := reflect.Append(valSlice, val)
    return slice
}

func main() {
    user := []User{}
    userInfo := []string{"Kostya", "pas", "m"}
    sl := AddInfo(&user, userInfo)
    fmt.Println(sl)
}
```

Код на Playground https://play.golang.org/p/ChOqzYreme
Код не идеальный но может кто дополнит